# How do I split strings based on a specific pattern using Python?

Tags: python, string

My string is of the form `my_str = "2a1^ath67e22^yz2p0"`. I would like to split based on the pattern `'^(any characters)` and get `["2a1", "67e22", "2p0"]`. The pattern could also appear in the front or the back part of the string, such as `^abc27e4` or `27c2^abc`. I tried `re.split("(.*)\^[a-z]{1,100}(.*)", my_str)` but it only splits one of those patterns. I am assuming here that the number of characters appearing after ^ will not be larger than 100.

Comment: I think your regex is just more complicated than it needs to be. `r"\^[a-z]+` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need regex for simple string operations, you can use

```
my_list = my_str.split('^')
```

EDIT: sorry, I just saw that you don't want to split just on the `^` character but also on strings following. Therefore you will need regex.

```
my_list = re.split('\^[a-z]+', my_str)
```

If the pattern is at the front or the end of the string, this will create an empty list element. you can remove them with

```
my_list = list(filter(None, my_list))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't know it was that easy haha

Answer (score -1):

if you want to use regex library, you can just split by '\^'

```
re.split('\^', my_str)

# output : ['2a1', 'ath67e22', 'yz2p0']
```